# Screen capture of external display on Android?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

Android apps, via the `Presentation` class and related facilities, can display separate content on an external display (HDMI, MHL, Miracast, etc.) than on a phone or tablet's own touchscreen (what I'll call the "primary display" here).

For the primary display, we can use `screencap` or DDMS to do a screenshot.

Is there a way to do a screenshot of the external display?

Ideally, it would be a solution that could be used akin to `screencap`/DDMS, with no app modifications. However, solutions that involve somehow copying the contents of the `Window` representing the external display would also be interesting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no OS feature for capturing the external display.

The main display is composited from a number of sources, as is the external display.  The "screen capture" feature is actually just another way to composite the various sources.  Because it uses the same parameters as the main display, you get the same output.  (Note that any "secure" layers, such as DRM-protected video, do not appear however.)  So to "capture" the external display, you'd want a screen capture variant that uses the external display "layer stack" rather than the main, and there is no API for doing so.

(See `SurfaceFlinger::captureScreenImplLocked()` in [SurfaceFlinger.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/lollipop-release/services/surfaceflinger/SurfaceFlinger.cpp).)

The `screenrecord` command does something similar: it creates a virtual display with the main display's layer stack, and captures whatever gets rendered there.

As far as capturing the output of a `Presentation` goes, there are a couple of CTS tests that may be of interest.  The [VirtualDisplayTest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/lollipop-release/tests/tests/display/src/android/display/cts/VirtualDisplayTest.java) creates a `Presentation` and captures it with an [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html), while [EncodeVirtualDisplayTest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/lollipop-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeVirtualDisplayTest.java) feeds the Presentation through a full video encode/decode path.  The tests just draw a series of colors and then check to make sure the colors can be read back.  Both of these require recent very versions of Android (e.g. `ImageReader` didn't exist until API 19), and the app's limited permissions will restrict the output to what the app itself is rendering.

Comment: how do you know all this :O

Comment: I kinda figured this was the situation, but I wasn't sure if I was missing some other option. I'll file a feature request for `screencap` and/or `screenrecord` to get a command-line switch to capture from an external display, which may drive adding the missing API. The problem with the CTS tests is that they route the `Presentation` output to a virtual display individually, whereas an app-driven screen capture mechanism would require routing the `Presentation` to a real external display *and* something for which we can do the screen capture.

Comment: @rupps: It wouldn't shock me if fadden wrote some of what we're discussing here... :-)