# How to capture a video of an external screen in Android?

Tags: android

I have an Android app running as a Presentation on a secondary display.
I'd like to record its screen in a way similar to `adb screenrecord`.
I searched the web but was unable to find anything except for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941104/screen-capture-of-external-display-on-android). That dates back to 2014 and I was wondering if there is a more intuitive way to do it now? I am an Android newbie so the answer to that question was unfortunately not very helpful to me.